# Sum the second value of each tuple in a list

Tags: python

Given structured data like `[('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('c', 2)]`, how can I sum the integers (here, sum `1 + 3 + 2` to get `6`) using the `sum` builtin, *in a single expression*?

Comment: Since OP already knew how to use `sum`, the question is really about how to *get data that can be summed* in a sub-expression passed to `sum`. This boils down to "how do I do something with each element of a list, and collect the results?", which is **extremely** commonly asked, but in **many** different forms. The closest canonical I have so far is [Apply function to each element of a list](/questions/25082410), but I am strongly considering doing a new canonical from scratch.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
sum(n for _, n in structure)
```

would work.

Comment: Surprisingly enough, this is marginally faster than my solution (on python 2.7, OS-X 10.5). -- using a list comprehension increases the speed here by almost 50% (for this small example).

Comment: The only weakness I can think of is that it won't work if one element happens to be `('a', 3, 'extra-data-to-ignore')`, whereas both the explicit index and the `zip` approaches -- even the `reduce` -- generalize a little better that way.  I guess in Py3 you could write `sum(b for _, b, *_ in structure)` or something..

Comment: @mgilson: took the words out of my mouth, I'd just run the tests myself (Python 2.7, OS-X 10.7). I've read before about how fast tuple unpacking is but it was interesting to see it in action. Might have to do with bound checking in the `x[1]` evaluation.

Comment: FWIW, I'd write this as `sum(n for _, n in structure)` to indicate the first item of each pair wasn't being used.

Comment: @martineau: I like it. It does look a little obscure, though (like the `_` is a special operator).

Comment: @DavidRobinson -- using `_` for unused elements when unpacking is a pretty well established python convention I think.

Comment: It's a fairly common Python idiom though which many would recognize immediately.

Comment: @mgilson: I meant for beginners seeing this. If I were a beginner I'd wonder if `_,` were a special operator.

Comment: I've noticed before that `_` for "don't care variables" is a bit controversial. Beginners coming from Prolog or Haskell should be used to it, though :)

Comment: @DSM: To avoid problems with extra data, one could write `import operator` then `sum(operator.itemgetter(1)(t) for t in structure)`.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: how can bounds checking matter here? `x, y = xy` does have to check whether `len(xy) == 2`, since otherwise it raises a `ValueError`.

Comment: @martineau: you definitely could, but in this case that seems like a *very* roundabout way of writing `t[1]`..

Comment: Prefer this answer to the others as it avoids using magic numbers.

Comment: For anyone who is new to Python (like me) and is wondering why this works: the sum contains one generator expression (not two arguments, this initially confused me). It is very similar to the answer by mgilson. You can find more about generator expressions here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generator-expressions/

Comment: This way is still slightly faster in 3.8; using a list comprehension instead of a generator expression is also still faster, though not by as much in my testing as @mgilson's. (My test data uses 10,000 pairs of (single-character string, single-digit integer).)

Answer (score 20):

```
sum(x[1] for x in structure)
```

should work

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
sum(zip(*structure)[1])
```

Comment: You could use `sum(map(operator.itemgetter(1),structure)` if you really want to avoid the comprehensions ... (but what's the point really?)

Comment: @DavidRobinson -- This new version with `zip` is marginally slower than our answers on python2.7 (OS-X 10.5).

Comment: @mgilson in 3.x, `zip` produces an iterable which must be manually unpacked before the `sum`. There aren't any elegant ways to make a single expression out of it (although of course many things can be put on one *line* using `;`) and this approach is *considerably* slower now (unpacking in a list comprehension is nearly twice as fast in my tests).

Answer (score 1):

Using a functional style, you could do

```
reduce(lambda x,y:x+y[1], structure,0)
```

Comment: Just a hint, functional programming methods almost got removed from `Python 3` reduce isn't event loaded by default anymore. So list comprehensions should be preferred in this case

Comment: Aside from that, OP *specifically* asked to use `sum`.