# Why such dramatic impacts from using indexes in Python loops?

Tags: python

I'm writing Python courseware and am teaching about nested `for` loops. I have four homegrown versions of `itertools.combinations(iterable, 2)` to compare, as follows:

combos.py:

```
import itertools

# baseline to compare
def combos_v1(iterable):
    return itertools.combinations(iterable, 2)

def combos_v2(iterable):
    a = []

    for elem1 in iterable[:-1]:
        iterable.pop(0)

        for elem2 in iterable:
            a.append((elem1, elem2))

    return a

def combos_v3(iterable):
    a = []

    for idx1, elem1 in enumerate(iterable[:-1]):
        for elem2 in iterable[idx1 + 1:]:
            a.append((elem1, elem2))

    return a

def combos_v4(iterable):
    a = []
    length = len(iterable)

    for idx1, elem1 in enumerate(iterable[:-1]):
        for idx2 in range(idx1 + 1, length):
            a.append((elem1, iterable[idx2]))

    return a

def combos_v5(iterable):
    a = []
    length = len(iterable)

    for idx1 in range(length - 1):
        for idx2 in range(idx1 + 1, length):
            a.append((iterable[idx1], iterable[idx2]))

    return a
```

I was prepared for the last three versions to be slower than the first two, but not over 1,000 times slower:

time_combos.py:

```
from timeit import timeit
times = []

for ver in range(1, 6):
    times.append(timeit(
        f"combos_v{ver}(it)",
        f"from combos import combos_v{ver}; it = [42]*100",
        number=10000))

print("Results:")

for ver, time in enumerate(times, start=1):
    print(f"v{ver}: {time} secs")
```

Output:

```
Results:
v1: 0.011828199999999999 secs
v2: 0.003176400000000003 secs
v3: 4.159025300000001 secs
v4: 4.5762011000000005 secs
v5: 5.252337500000001 secs
```

What's happening under the hood that makes the versions that use indexes in some way *so* much slower than `combos_v2`? I actually thought `combos_v3` was going to be the slowest because it copies the list in each iteration of the outer loop, but it's not significantly different from the non-copying versions.

**EDIT**

I suspect the answer is not because of indexing. Instead, I think the slowdown is from Python's use of unlimited precision integers. The _v3, _v4, and _v5 options all either explicitly or implicitly (in `enumerate()`) do integer math, which I believe is more expensive with unlimited precision integers than it is with CPU native integers. I don't have a good way of testing this, though. I can verify that iterating over a range is slower than iterating over a list:

```
>>> timeit("for __ in range(10000): pass", number=10000)
1.565418199999982
>>> timeit("for __ in it: pass", "it = list(range(10000))", number=10000)
0.6037281999999777
```

but it's not thousands of times slower, so I'm not sure whether that accounts for what I'm seeing. I can compare iterating over a range vs. indexing *without* integer math:

```
>>> timeit("for el in range(10000): el", number=10000)
1.8875144000000432
>>> timeit("for __ in it: it[42]", "it = list(range(10000))", number=10000)
2.2635267
```

but I think this is an apples-to-oranges comparison. I tried rewriting some of the slow versions using `numpy.uint64` integers and they were marginally faster, but I don't know how much overhead I'm incurring from `numpy`.

Comment: `combos_v2()` is doing a lot less work than the other versions, because it's *utterly broken*.  Removing elements from a list that you're iterating over typically results in half the elements being skipped.  Before worrying about time comparisons, you should check that your various versions are actually producing the same results...

Comment: @jasonharper - thanks for your response. Please check the code carefully. The slice operation in the outer loop makes a *copy* of `iterable`, so it's safe to `pop()` from it in the outer loop. The code does work.

Comment: I'm not sure how you arrived at that conclusion from the given link @Gulzar.

Comment: @Gulzar - thanks. Slices of a list return a new list that is a shallow copy of the selected elements of the old list (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)). You can see this for yourself: `list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]; list2 = list1[:-1]; list1.pop(0); print(type(list1), list1, type(list2), list2)`. The only View objects I know of are Dictionary Views (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)).

Comment: The [dis module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dis.html) is great for giving you hints about this kind of thing. Also, very related question that may be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024416/how-come-unpacking-is-faster-than-accessing-by-index

Comment: @skrrgwasme - thanks for the suggestion on `dis`. Unfortunately I don't know enough of the internals of the Python VM to be able to ID the offending opcodes and I don't have the time to learn. I'm going to consign this question to my list of things beyond my grasp.

Comment: @JohnRiehl Your `combos_v1` function actually returns an iterator. Since that one is not consumed (iterated over), not a single combination gets ever calculated and its run time is more or less constant, independent from the input length. Simply return `list(itertools.combinations(iterable, 2))` and suddenly run times will be more realistic. As to be expected, it still beats the last three methods.

Comment: @amain Good catch, thanks! I'm still stumped as to why `combos_v2` is so much faster than every other approach, including that of `itertools.combinations()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was written with two guiding principles:

- When you want to answer performance questions, you need to play a game of *find the hot loop*.
- **Notice when you are confused**: it means that something you believe is wrong.

To start with, let's look at your testing code:

```
for ver in range(1, 6):
    times.append(timeit(
        f"combos_v{ver}(it)",
        f"from combos import combos_v{ver}; it = [42]*100",
        number=10000))
```

Your testing code runs `combos_vn(it)` with the same `list` object, 10000 times.

### `combos_v1`

```
def combos_v1(iterable):
    return itertools.combinations(iterable, 2)
```

`dis.dis` tells us:

```
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (itertools)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (combinations)
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (iterable)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              8 CALL_METHOD              2
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Each of these opcodes only runs once, so it's unlikely they contribute significantly to the execution time. The hot loop is in `itertools.combinations`; let's see [how it's implemented](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c). (I've cut bits out of this code for readability; what's left is more like pseudocode.)

```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    PyObject *pool;         /* input converted to a tuple */
    Py_ssize_t *indices;    /* one index per result element */
    PyObject *result;       /* most recently returned result tuple */
    Py_ssize_t r;           /* size of result tuple */
    int stopped;            /* set to 1 when the iterator is exhausted */
} combinationsobject;

// in itertools.combinations.__new__
    pool = PySequence_Tuple(iterable);
    if (pool == NULL)
        goto error;

// in itertools.combinations.__next__
    if (result == NULL) {
        /* On the first pass, initialize result tuple using the indices */
        for (i=0; i<r ; i++) {
            index = indices[i];
            elem = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(pool, index);
            Py_INCREF(elem);
            PyTuple_SET_ITEM(result, i, elem);
        }
    } else {
        /* Copy the previous result tuple or re-use it if available */
        if (Py_REFCNT(result) > 1) {
            result = _PyTuple_FromArray(_PyTuple_ITEMS(old_result), r);
            Py_DECREF(old_result);
        }

        /* Now, we've got the only copy so we can update it in-place
         * CPython's empty tuple is a singleton and cached in
         * PyTuple's freelist.
         */
        assert(r == 0 || Py_REFCNT(result) == 1);

        /* Scan indices right-to-left until finding one that is not
           at its maximum (i + n - r). */
        for (i=r-1 ; i >= 0 && indices[i] == i+n-r ; i--)
            ;

        /* If i is negative, then the indices are all at
           their maximum value and we're done. */
        if (i < 0)
            goto empty;

        /* Increment the current index which we know is not at its
           maximum.  Then move back to the right setting each index
           to its lowest possible value (one higher than the index
           to its left -- this maintains the sort order invariant). */
        indices[i]++;
        for (j=i+1 ; j<r ; j++)
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1;

        /* Update the result tuple for the new indices
           starting with i, the leftmost index that changed */
        for ( ; i<r ; i++) {
            index = indices[i];
            elem = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(pool, index);
            Py_INCREF(elem);
            oldelem = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(result, i);
            PyTuple_SET_ITEM(result, i, elem);
            Py_DECREF(oldelem);
        }
```

We see that `itertools.combinations` is lazy; it returns an iterator, and does most of its work in the `__next__` method of that iterator.

> Your testing code runs `combos_vn(it)` with the same `list` object, 10000 times.

`combos_v1` runs `tuple(iterable)` in *preparation*, but since you never iterate over its return value, the combinations don't get calculated. That's why it's so fast: it's only looping over the iterable once (in `__new__`)! This isn't a fair comparison.

### `combos_v2`

```
def combos_v2(iterable):
    a = []

    for elem1 in iterable[:-1]:
        iterable.pop(0)

        for elem2 in iterable:
            a.append((elem1, elem2))

    return a
```

Let's try running this and see what happens.

```
>>> l = [3, 4, 5]
>>> combos_v2(l)
[(3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)]
>>> l
[5]
>>> combos_v2(l)
[]
>>> l
[5]
```

What happened? Well, `iterable.pop(0)` happened. This method removes the first item from the list; there's no code to add items back once it's done.

> Your testing code runs `combos_vn(it)` with the same `list` object, 10000 times.

You've measured the time of 1 call with a 100-element list, and 9999 calls with a 1-element list. This isn't a fair comparison, either.

### `combos_v3`

```
def combos_v3(iterable):
    a = []

    for idx1, elem1 in enumerate(iterable[:-1]):
        for elem2 in iterable[idx1 + 1:]:
            a.append((elem1, elem2))

    return a
```

I ran `dis.dis` again; here are the interesting parts:

```
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (iterable)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (-1)
             12 BUILD_SLICE              2
             14 BINARY_SUBSCR
```

This corresponds to the code `iterable[:-1]`. Let's have a look at [the implementation of](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c) `BINARY_SUBSCR` of a `list` and a `slice`:

```c
static PyObject *
list_slice(PyListObject *a, Py_ssize_t ilow, Py_ssize_t ihigh)
{
    PyListObject *np;
    PyObject **src, **dest;
    Py_ssize_t i, len;
    len = ihigh - ilow;
    if (len <= 0) {
        return PyList_New(0);
    }
    np = (PyListObject *) list_new_prealloc(len);
    if (np == NULL)
        return NULL;

    src = a->ob_item + ilow;
    dest = np->ob_item;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        PyObject *v = src[i];
        Py_INCREF(v);
        dest[i] = v;
    }
    Py_SET_SIZE(np, len);
    return (PyObject *)np;
}
```

It might not look like much, but this little `iterable[:-1]` is performing an allocation and a copy of 99 elements. The copy's not *much* – that's only an O(n) loop, not an O(n²) – but it's still something; and allocating memory has a chance of getting the operating system involved, which can be a *really* expensive operation. (If there's not enough free memory, the OS has to start swapping to disk…)

```
  5          28 LOAD_FAST                0 (iterable)
             30 LOAD_FAST                2 (idx1)
             32 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             34 BINARY_ADD
             36 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             38 BUILD_SLICE              2
             40 BINARY_SUBSCR
```

Another list slice! This one gets run *every outer loop*; it's an Θ(n) cost run n-1 times, which is Θ(n²). *That's* probably significant with a large list… but your list only has 100 elements.

Since the slice-created list's refcount hits 0 before the next list is created, its buffer is freed before a new (one element smaller) one needs to be allocated. Most C runtimes allocate blocks of memory from the OS, and then divide that up when the program needs it; since the memory required is quite small (99 or fewer elements), the C runtime's allocator is probably re-using the same region of pre-allocated memory, meaning the OS never gets involved. The extra copies probably don't even leave the CPU's cache!

We probably didn't need to look at the opcodes at all for this one, because that's not where the computer's spending most of its time, even in theory. To quote Donald Knuth:

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.

### `combos_v4`

```
def combos_v4(iterable):
    a = []
    length = len(iterable)

    for idx1, elem1 in enumerate(iterable[:-1]):
        for idx2 in range(idx1 + 1, length):
            a.append((elem1, iterable[idx2]))

    return a
```

*This* one, it's probably worth thinking about bytecode for. Compared to `combos_v3`, `combos_v4` is missing the list slice in the outer loop, so only has 1 extra Θ(n)-sized allocation. In exchange, though, it runs `iterable[idx2]` Θ(n²) times.

Let's just do an isolated comparison of those two:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('for item in l: item', 'l = list(range(100))')
1.4886210270342417
>>> timeit('for i in range(100): l[i]', 'l = list(range(100))')
3.4677056610235013
>>> timeit('for item in l: item', 'l = list(range(1000))')
14.140142865013331
>>> timeit('for i in range(1000): l[i]', 'l = list(range(1000))')
36.24445745302364
```

This isn't very rigorous, but it demonstrates the point: iterating over a list with `range` takes over twice as long as using Python's built-in list iterator. This effect could cancel out the savings from not doing that copy.

### `combos_v5`

```
def combos_v5(iterable):
    a = []
    length = len(iterable)

    for idx1 in range(length - 1):
        for idx2 in range(idx1 + 1, length):
            a.append((iterable[idx1], iterable[idx2]))

    return a
```

If `combos_v4` is slower than `combos_v3`, then `combos_v5` will probably be slower than both, for the same reason.

### Fixed test harness

To test `combos_v1` properly, we need to fix that test harness. It needs to consume the iterator; I happen to know that `collections.deque` has a special-cased code path for doing that as fast as possible if `maxlen=0`.

To test `combos_v2` properly, we need to reset the list each loop. I can't work out how to do that without it contributing to the time, so I'll just make the list a `tuple` instead.

```py
from collections import deque
for ver in range(16):
    try:
        times.append(timeit(
            f"deque(combos_v{ver+1}(it), maxlen=0)",
            f"from combos import combos_v{ver+1}; it = tuple([42]*100)",
            number=10000,
            globals=globals()))
    except Exception as e:
        times.append(e)
```

### Improved versions

There are a few ways to improve `combos_v2`. The trivial solution is to make it copy the list at the beginning:

```py
def combos_v7(iterable):
    a = []
    l = list(iterable)

    for elem1 in l[:-1]:
        l.pop(0)

        for elem2 in l:
            a.append((elem1, elem2))

    return a
```

If you do this, you'll notice that this is quite slow. The culprit is `l.pop(0)`. The implementation of `pop` is quite heavily optimised and hard to understand, so I'll paraphrase: CPython represents lists as a heap-allocated array of `object`s. When you remove the first one, it has to move all of the others back by 1. Repeating `l.pop(0)` until there's only one item left in the list requires Θ(n²) moves.

We can fix this by reversing the list, then popping from the end:

```py
def combos_v8(iterable):
    a = []
    l = list(reversed(iterable))

    for elem1 in reversed(l[1:]):
        l.pop(-1)

        for elem2 in reversed(l):
            a.append((elem1, elem2))

    return a
```

`combo_v5` has a (potential) trivial improvement, too. Instead of doing `iterable[idx1]` every inner loop, only do it on the outer loop:

```py
def combos_v9(iterable):
    a = []
    length = len(iterable)

    for idx1 in range(length - 1):
        item1 = iterable[idx1]
        for idx2 in range(idx1 + 1, length):
            a.append((item1, iterable[idx2]))

    return a
```

And finally, the most marginal optimisation I can think of: removing lookups for `itertools.combinations` in `combos_v1`:

```py
from itertools import combinations
def combos_v10(iterable):
    return combinations(iterable, 2)

def combos_v11(iterable, combinations=itertools.combinations):
    return combinations(iterable, 2)

combos_v12 = (lambda c: lambda i: c(i, 2))(itertools.combinations)

from types import FunctionType, CodeType
combos_v13 = FunctionType(CodeType(1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 65, b'd\x00|\x00d\x01\x83\x02S\x00', (itertools.combinations, 2), (), ('iterable',), 'custom', 'combos_v13', 9001, b''), globals())
```

### Other versions

`itertools.islice` is like a hybrid between the slice version and the `range` version: it does the iteration in C, with fixed-width C integers, but it doesn't need a copy operation to do so – to "remove" the elements at the beginning, it repeatedly calls `next` on the iterator.

```py
from itertools import islice

def combos_v14(iterable):
    a = []
    for i, x in enumerate(iterable, start=1):
        for y in islice(iterable, i, None):
            a.append((x, y))
    return a

def combos_v15(iterable):
    return [
        (x, y)
        for i, x in enumerate(iterable, start=1)
        for y in islice(iterable, i, None)
    ]
```

`combos_v15` is just `combos_v14` with a list comprehension. I expect that to be slightly faster, for two reasons:

- The list doesn't have to be in a valid state while it's being constructed, since it doesn't need to be exposed to Python; CPython might have an optimisation that relies on this.
- It's not constantly looking up `.append` on `a`.

`itertools.islice` has to iterate through the whole beginning of the list to get to the point we want. Wouldn't it be nice if we didn't have to do that? Well, I found a nice little implementation detail in the source code:

```c
PyDoc_STRVAR(length_hint_doc, "Private method returning an estimate of len(list(it)).");
PyDoc_STRVAR(reduce_doc, "Return state information for pickling.");
PyDoc_STRVAR(setstate_doc, "Set state information for unpickling.");

static PyMethodDef listiter_methods[] = {
    {"__length_hint__", (PyCFunction)listiter_len, METH_NOARGS, length_hint_doc},
    {"__reduce__", (PyCFunction)listiter_reduce, METH_NOARGS, reduce_doc},
    {"__setstate__", (PyCFunction)listiter_setstate, METH_O, setstate_doc},
    {NULL,              NULL}           /* sentinel */
};
```

This is for the `pickle` module, which has a pure-Python version. List iterators can be pickled, which means there's a way to set their start index *at runtime*! Let's give it a spin.

```
>>> l = [3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> i = iter(l)
>>> i.__reduce__()
(<built-in function iter>, ([3, 4, 5, 6],), 0)
>>> next(i)
3
>>> i.__setstate__(0)
>>> next(i)
3
>>> i.__setstate__(2)
>>> list(i)
[5, 6]
```

Let's use it!

```py
def combos_v16(iterable):
    a = []
    for i, x in enumerate(iterable, start=1):
        list_iter = iter(iterable)
        list_iter.__setstate__(i)
        for y in list_iter:
            a.append((x, y))
    return a
```

Unfortunately, we can't *easily* create a list comprehension version of this. I could do it with CPython bytecode, of course, but that's hackish even by *my* standards. It should probably re-use `list_iter` instead of creating it anew each loop; I'll add that when I re-do the answer.

We could also drop down to `ctypes` and try to clone the outermost list iterator. This is a *horribly* unsafe thing to do, and I'm not confident it'd be any faster. I might add it when I rewrite this answer.

### Final comparison

These were run on Python 3.9.2 on a [INSERT ARCH HERE] machine.

#### 100-long list (10000 repeats)

```
 v1: 0.5226162209874019 secs
 v2: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'pop' secs
 v3: 4.440105640038382 secs
 v4: 5.242078252020292 secs
 v5: 5.847154696006328 secs
 v6: name 'combos_v6' is not defined secs
 v7: 4.175016652967315 secs
 v8: 4.296667369024362 secs
 v9: 5.217006383987609 secs
v10: 0.4311756350216456 secs
v11: 0.4331229960080236 secs
v12: 0.4280035650008358 secs
v13: 0.4272943940013647 secs
v14: 4.696938373963349 secs
v15: 3.6629469400504604 secs
v16: 4.158298808033578 secs
```

#### 1000-long list (1000 repeats)

I was doing other things on my computer while this was running, so the results are likely noisier.

```
 v1: 4.355944950017147 secs
 v2: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'pop' secs
 v3: 65.12864276999608 secs
 v4: 80.17008238798007 secs
 v5: 84.949459077965 secs
 v6: name 'combos_v6' is not defined secs
 v7: 69.36186740599805 secs
 v8: 64.24041850597132 secs
 v9: 77.76190268195933 secs
v10: 4.170568476023618 secs
v11: 4.219949325022753 secs
v12: 4.133982014027424 secs
v13: 4.188805791025516 secs
v14: 67.87807830097154 secs
v15: 57.55693690601038 secs
v16: 64.51734905398916 secs
```

#### 10000-long list (1000 repeats)

(Crashed Python for some reason.)

These results make a lot more sense. No implementation with Python in the inner loop beats an implementation with a pure-C inner loop, but the pure-C implementations are roughly a constant factor faster; and there's not that much difference between various Python implementations. The fastest Python version uses a list comprehension.

---

Aside: what you're calling an `iterable` is actually an `indexable`. I haven't corrected your variable names in my answer, but I probably should.

Comment: Thanks for taking so much time with this! I feel silly to have missed the problem with the testing harness on v2. There's so much to learn in the rest of your answer.