# calculate average sum from second value of each tuple in python

Tags: python

I used this here to sum the second value of each tuple in a list: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12218119/9195816

`sum(n for _, n in structure)` works fine. But i dont need the sum, i only need the average. So something like `sum(n for _, n in structure) \ total_amount_of_values`. But of course, this won't work:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'list'

My list looks i.e. like this: [1000, 900.84, 500, 1240.11]

Comment: The error is stating you are trying to divide a float and a list, can you provide  the contents for the variables you are dividing?

Comment: how does your tuple look like? Also, *"But i dont need the sum, i also need the average"* this is not clear. Do you or do you **not** need the sum?

Comment: Do this, `sum(n for _, n in structure) / len(structure)`

Comment: @Stack You can just divide with `len(structure)`

Comment: Sorry, i only need the average.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis , fixed it my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = [1000, 900.84, 500, 1240.11]
average = sum(n)/len(n)
```

This will give you the average of the list `n`

---

But it sounds like your list looks more like this

```
n = [(a,b), (c,d), ...]
```

and you want

```
b + d + ... / len(n)
```

If this is the case, then you can do this like so

```
average = sum(map(lambda x: x[1], n)) / len(n)
```