# How to use reduce function here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, reduce

I am trying to find total of all the integers in a tuple

```
from  functools  import reduce
marks =  [("Jon" ,29 ), ("santi",35), ("anna",35)]

Total_marks = lambda x,y: x[1]

print(marks)
print (reduce(Total_marks,marks))
```

The above code can take the first value of integer, but i want to find the sum of all  the integers, how to do it using reduce in python

Comment: Do you **have** to use `reduce`? `sum(score for name, score in marks)` is much more readable in my opinion.

Comment: @LakshayGarg , sure, post it please

Comment: As suggested in other post, you can try `print(reduce(lambda x,y:x+y[1], marks,0))` https://stackoverflow.com/a/12218359/5916727

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the definition of the adding function (there is no need to use lambda notation here):

```
def total_marks(x, y): 
    return x + y[1]
```

And tell `reduce` that the initial value is a number, not a tuple, by providing the third optional parameter:

```
reduce(total_marks, marks, 0)
#99
```

The same solution with lambda:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x+y[1], marks, 0)
```

And one more solution that does not use `reduce`:

```
_, y = zip(*marks)
sum(y)
#99
```

Comment: Wonderful... ...

Answer (score 3):

If using reduce is not necessary, a much more elegant solution is

```
marks =  [("Jon" ,29 ), ("santi",35), ("anna",35)]
total_marks = sum(score for _, score in marks)
print(total_marks)
```

Comment: this is easy and can  u post the full code

Comment: @Karamzov I have updated the code

Comment: How does the sum and for works here, how they knew to read the values ?

Comment: `sum` is a builtin function is python which can be used to sum iterables (lists, tuples, generators etc). The interesting part here is `score for _, score in marks`. This is what is called a list comprehension. A comment would be too short to explain what it does, please see this [blog](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/). Googling "list comprehensions in python" will help too.

Comment: ok ... helpful ....

Comment: I changed the first set as `(2,29)` and run the code but still my result is 99 , not 101 ,  from your code how the list comprehension knows to sum the second value in list

Answer (score 2):

You would use [`operator.itemgetter(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to get the numbers out of the tuple, and `reduce` with [`operator.add`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.add) to sum them

```
from  functools  import reduce
from operator import itemgetter, add
marks =  [("Jon" ,29 ), ("santi",35), ("anna",35)]

print(reduce(add, map(itemgetter(1), marks)))
# 99
```

A simpler solution without `reduce` is `sum(mark for name, mark in marks)`

Comment: Or even `sum(map(itemgetter(1), marks))` for the simpler solution.

Comment: thanks patrick....

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the first parameter (`x`) is a tuple:

```
from functools import reduce
marks = [("Jon" ,29 ), ("santi",35), ("anna",35)]
new_marks = reduce(lambda x, y:(x if isinstance(x, int) else x[-1])+y[-1], marks)
assert new_marks == sum(b for _, b in marks)
print(new_marks)
```

Output:

```
99
```

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I feel this is an overly complicated use of `reduce` when you could instead provide the initial value: `reduce(lambda x, y: x + y[1], marks, 0)`. What happens otherwise is that `reduce` takes the first value as accumulator, which adds the unecessary complexity.

Comment: good one.. thank you

Comment: @Karamzov Glad to help!